# Taking pictures/videos from both front and rear camera simultaneously?

Tags: root-access, camera, hardware, images, front-camera

There are apps that can do this but they are not  exactly Bothie. The app allows the user to first take a picture from rear camera and then from the front camera (but not simultaneously). Nokia first came up with this idea in 2017.
[More about Bothie](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-bothie-4158927)

I am just wondering if this is a hardware feature or software. I can handle the software issue(with root) i think. And if this is not possible then can you please explain why and how it works (totally optional)?
Because if this is possible then people will be able to take videos from both cameras (poor cameraman will also be included in the clip).. and that would be pretty cool IMO =)

Every little opinion or googling is accepted. Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could gather from answers on Stack Overflow. I have no development background, so corrections are welcome.

- Camera could have only have one object as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24360809). But this was depreciated from [Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29). So, devices running KitKat and below, *cannot* have this feature.
- It seemed to be possible on some devices to open both front and rear camera as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25144412). However, it is not possible on all devices due to **[hardware & Software restrictions (see comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444841)**

> The Android camera APIs generally allow multiple cameras to be used at the same time, but most devices do not have enough hardware resources to support that in practice - for example, there's often only one camera image processor shared by both cameras.

- The link in your question is the best I could find for a clear explanation.Nokia, Samsung, LG seem to have started this trend on some of their devices. Such devices either need [Dual Camera Mode](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS980/Userguide/246.html) or [Dual Sight Mode](https://www.lifewire.com/nokia-8-dual-sight-4159343). There wasn't much I could find about these OEM specific technologies. The [Frontback Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dualcamera.frontback.camerainstantly.front.camera) app mentioned in the link, works on Pixel 4a Android 11. **Note** that the pictures were very grainy and not worth the result IMO.

OP tried [apps mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377081/access-both-back-and-front-cameras-simultaneously/30444841#30444841) and they didn't work.

This  leads me to conclude that it is both a hardware & Software feature and apps can be poor substitute. I doubt if trying on other devices would show better results. Neither have I come across any rooted or Xposed modules that can do this, so it is best to buy the devices that support this natively, if you want this feature badly.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching a dual camera for my vlog but could find nowhere.

However, I want to give you some good news. Such camera is possible and I had found it on POCO X3 NFC MIUI camera. My friend uses this phone and dual camera works at a same time. I wasn't able to transfer that app through shareMe app, so I couldn't use that app for my mobile.

I thoroughly searched on google and haven't found anyone.
If you have found, do let me know.

Comment: Just like [beeshyams' answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231898/44325) mentioned, I think this is a customization done on POCO devices, I doubt the app would work on other devices.

Comment: @AndrewT. is right.

Comment: @AndrewT, I found a few more apps on the play store. You can find it as a dual camera. Basically, this device works with snapdragon mobile. The problem with them is that I couldn't reshape the screen size, and the camera doesn't seem to be so good.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you want to check if your device is compatible.. Download two 3rd party camera apps.. Grant them the permission.. Split screen and try to open both the camera apps.. If one of the app crashes when you open the second app then there is some hardware restrictions in your device.